# Regular expression in sed command

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I want to use sed command to change one(width to be exact) parameter in a file. In this case it is motion.conf in motion program for motion detection.

I have written a command for line replacment but it is not working, as I want it to work. This is the command:

```
sudo sed 's/width [0-9]/change/g' /etc/motion/motion.conf
```

The selection of the line works only when I have `[0-9]` written. If I place `[0-9]+` the ommand does not work anymore.

Can you please tell me how to make it work.

Thanks

Comment: You can either escape the `+` quantifier with a backslash or use the extended regex option with `sed`. Else the plus character isn't treated as special.

Comment: @some-non-descript-user I escaped the + sign, it works, thanks. I didnt know that the + sign has to be escaped

Answer (score 3):

All you need to do is escape the `+`:

```
$ cat a
xxx width 0 hallo
xxx width 12 hallo
$ sed 's/width [0-9]\+/change/g' a
xxx change hallo
xxx change hallo
```

You can find the regex syntax for GNU sed [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Regular-Expressions.html).

Comment: As a side comment: I always get confused what regular expression flavor applies to which command line tool. I decided to learn one of them and then use flags to apply a particular flavor as much as possible. For `sed`, that would be `sed -r`, as @some-non-descript-user noted.

Comment: Thanks it works. I didnt know about escaping. Also thanks for the link

Answer (score 2):

Note that sed uses by default the POSIX BRE (Basic Regular Expression) syntax. In the POSIX specification `+` doesn't exist, but many linux implementations have added it. To obtain a more portable pattern, you can write:

```
sed 's/width [0-9][0-9]*/change/g'
```

or

```
sed 's/width [0-9]\{1,\}/change/g'
```

*But curly brackets quantifiers are not supported in some older versions.*

You can also switch the regular expression syntax to ERE (Extended Regular Expression) that supports the `+` quantifier and doesn't need to be escaped:

```
sed -r 's/width [0-9]+/change/g'
```

*(the `-r` option may be different ( for example: `-E`) depending of your sed version.)*

You can look around these syntaxes [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#POSIX_basic_and_extended).